# Convert SVG image to a path description

Tags: javascript, jquery, angularjs, svg

Essentially, I'm using an API that returns an svg image to me hosted on a different domain.

I'd like to use it as a `path` instead of an `image` so that I can manipulate the `fill` and `stroke`. As it stands currently, I'm not able to do so.

This is my code:

```
<svg height="100%" width="100%" position>
     <rect x="0" y="0" width="100%" height="100%" fill="#288feb"></rect>
     <g class="groupLayer">
          <image xlink:href="" ng-href="{{ctrl.iconObject[0].icon_url}}" x="0" y="-40" height="50px"/>
          <text fill="#ffffff" x="0" y="0" font-size="48" font-family="Verdana">{{ctrl.text}}</text>
     </g>
</svg>
```

So instead of `<image>` I'd like to use `<path d=`

like an example online I found does:

```
<path d="M577.21,131.86l4.06,12.5a3.36,3.36,0,0,0,3.19,2.32h13.14a2.36,2.36,0,0,1,1.39,4.27l-10.63,7.72a3.36,3.36,0,0,0-1.22,3.75l4.06,12.5a2.36,2.36,0,0,1-3.63,2.64l-10.63-7.72a3.36,3.36,0,0,0-3.94,0l-10.63,7.72a2.36,2.36,0,0,1-3.63-2.64l4.06-12.5a3.36,3.36,0,0,0-1.22-3.75l-10.63-7.72a2.36,2.36,0,0,1,1.39-4.27h13.14a3.36,3.36,0,0,0,3.19-2.32l4.06-12.5A2.36,2.36,0,0,1,577.21,131.86Z" transform="translate(-549.97 -130.23)"></path>
```

Is this possible with JavaScript? Maybe PHP? Thanks for the help.

Comment: Yes it's possible, but not straightforward. For js, this all depends on the external server settings. If it does allow cross-origin requests, then you can fetch the svg file (either with `fetch()` or XHR APIs) , parse it's text content with a DOMParser and include the elements you want in your own svg node. If it doesn't allow cross-origin requests, you'll then have to fetch the data from php, then apply the same as above but from your own server's response.

Comment: @Kaiido Oh brilliant! I didn't know that. Thanks!

Comment: What type of file does the `<image>` reference?  For instance, is it another SVG with paths in it, or is it a bitmap image?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I figured it out. It was quite simple in the end by simply using `XMLHttpRequest`:

```
function reqListener () {
  console.log(this.responseText);
}

var oReq = new XMLHttpRequest();
oReq.addEventListener("load", reqListener);
oReq.open("GET", "http://www.example.org/example.svg");
oReq.send();
```

you can then get the path data